# Runtime import possible?

Tags: vb.net

I will try to explain the problem as clearly as possible. I am not sure if what I need is possible but expect that there must be some solution to this. I wont be able to put in actual code here but will add whatever is needed to explain the problem.

Initially we had two separate classes as defined below.

```
Imports QMember48

Public Class Member48

 Public Function ProcessInfo(reqctx as Member48.RequestContext, memid as String)
 'Code here
 End Function

 Public Function UpdateInfo(partner as Member48.Partner, memid as String)
 'Code here
 End Function

 'Other methods and functions come here

End Class

Imports QMember50

Public Class Member50

 Public Function ProcessInfo(reqctx as Member50.RequestContext, memid as String)
 'Code here
 End Function

 Public Function UpdateInfo(partner as Member50.Partner, memid as String)
 'Code here
 End Function

 'Other methods and functions come here

End Class
```

Basically these two classes have common methods and functions but the references are different.

We next decided to create a factory pattern to get the objects of these classes based on some input parameter.

Our current implementation of code is like this:

```
'Base class definition
Imports QMember48

Public MustInherit Class Member
 Public MustOverride Function ProcessInfo(reqctx as Member48.RequestContext, memid as String)
 Public MustOverride Function UpdateInfo(partner as Member48.Partner, memid as String)
End Class

'Factory
Public Module MemFactory

 Function GetMember(val as string) as Member
  'Do some processing here
  If val = "500" return new Member50() else return new Member48()
 End Function

End Module
```

The problem is that the base class refers to Member48 and when the factory generates an object for Member50, the reference to Member48 still remains. This needs to be corrected somehow in the base class. If an object of Member50 is needed, there should not be any reference to Member48. But again how do we define the base class without any hardcoded import of Member48/50 ?

Is there any way to resolve this issue? If more details are needed, I can add later.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both `Members` don't have any method in common. There may be two methods with the same name, but those methods have different signatures. You can neither pass a `Member48.RequestContext` to a `Member50`, nor can you pass a `Member50.RequestContext` to a `Member48`. That's why inheritance can't applied here reasonably. A common base class of both members would be empty.

You could use a generic base class as follows:

```
MustInherit Class Member(Of TRequest, TPartner)
    Public MustOverride Function ProcessInfo(reqctx As TRequest, memid As String)
    Public MustOverride Function UpdateInfo(partner As TPartner, memid As String)
End Class

Class Member48
    Inherits Member(Of QMember48.RequestContext, QMember48.Partner)
    '...
End Class

Class Member50
    Inherits Member(Of QMember50.RequestContext, QMember50.Partner)
    '...
End Class
```

However, this base class does not give you any advantage with a factory. The factory would have to return an untyped `Member` and you'll lose any advantage of the generic implementation.

Another approach is trying to unify the `RequestContexts` and `Partners`. If the members only rely on common members, this can be done very easily with an interface. If there are no common members, you could even use an empty interface (as a hint of the requested type) and do the following:

```
MustInherit Class Member
    Public MustOverride Function ProcessInfo(reqctx As IRequestContext, memid As String)
    '...
End Class
```

The concrete `Member` would be responsible for checking for the correct type and could throw an exception if the wrong type is being passed.

The last approach is to go without any base class and let the factory return an `Object` (or maybe an empty base class). This might be the cleanest solution because it does not introduce any artificial inheritance where there is none. Of course, you would have to do type checks each time you access the object, but that is the same with most other methods.

Finally, there is not really a nice solution for your problem. Maybe you could revise your architecture and see if there are smarter structures or if you really need the `Members` as listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Create a baseclass or interface for `RequestContext` and `Partner`, and let `Member48.RequestContext`/`Member50.RequestContext` and `Member48.Partner`/`Member50.Partner` implement those interfaces:

```
Public Interface IRequestContext
End Interface

Public Interface IPartner
End Interface

Class Member48RequestContext
    Implements IRequestContext
End Class

Class Member48Partner
    Implements IPartner
End Class

Class Member50RequestContext
    Implements IRequestContext
End Class

Class Member50Partner
    Implements IPartner
End Class
```

Now you can create a base class that accepts an `IRequestContest` and an `IPartner`:

```
Public MustInherit Class Member
    Public MustOverride Function ProcessInfo(reqctx as IRequestContext, memid as String)
    Public MustOverride Function UpdateInfo(partner as IPartner, memid as String)
End Class
```

and the implementation of your concrete member classes look like

```
Public Class Member50
    Inherits Member

    Public Overrides Function ProcessInfo(reqctx as IRequestContext, memid as String)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function UpdateInfo(partner as IPartner, memid as String)
    End Function

End Class
```

If you want, you could also create another subclass using generics:

```
Public MustInherit Class Member(Of TRequest As IRequestContext, TPartner As IPartner) 
    Inherits Member

    Public Overrides Function ProcessInfo(reqctx as IRequestContext, memid as String)
        Return ProcessInfo(DirectCast(reqctx, TRequest), memid)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function UpdateInfo(partner as IPartner, memid as String)
        Return UpdateInfo(DirectCast(partner, TPartner), memid)
    End Function

    Public Overloads MustOverride Function ProcessInfo(reqctx as TRequest, memid as String)
    Public Overloads MustOverride Function UpdateInfo(partner as TPartner, memid as String)
End Class
```

and an implementation:

```
Public Class Member48
    Inherits Member(Of Member48RequestContext, Member48Partner) 

    Public Overrides Function ProcessInfo(reqctx as Member48RequestContext, memid as String)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function UpdateInfo(partner as Member48Partner, memid as String)
    End Function

End Class
```

Note how `Member48` only accepts an `Member48RequestContext` , instead of any `IRequestContext` like `Member50`. It's up to you if you want this extra safety.

Your factory method stays the same:

```
Function GetMember(val as string) as Member
    'Do some processing here
    If val = "500" Then
        Return New Member50()
    Else 
        Return New Member48()
    End If      
End Function
```

However, your factory still needs a reference to *both* `Member50` and `Member48`, since it creates the concrete classes.

Another approach is to use a DI-container like [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/), which is able to scan all your assemblies automatically for all types that implement `Member(Of TRequest As IRequestContext, TPartner As IPartner)`, asign a key to each one, and return the correct instance ,e.g. `Member50` if asked for a specifig key, e.g. 500. But a full blown example of such a configuration would be out of scope of this question/answer.

Comment: Thanks to all for helping me with this. I tried the process suggested by Dominic and it helped me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: @abanerjee: Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you most and possibly upvote any answer that you feel deserves an upvote.